# fancybox not diplaying despite no error in console(besides normal ones)

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I've gone over the questions i've found here and no one seemed to have a similar problem.
the website I'm working on is located at

view-source:http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/blog/cars/

a breakdown of things related to fancybox is

line 73 jquery included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
```

line 74 jquery-min included

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
```

line 138 fancybox js included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/wp-content/themes/Divi%20-%20child/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

line 139 fancybox css included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/wp-content/themes/Divi%20-%20child/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

throughout document: links surrounding cars (use same class as debugging link at bottom, first three cars are omitted, cause overlay is supposed to be the same info as displayed at the top)

line 2059 jquery.fancybox() called inside a document ready function

```
jQuery("a.car_overlay").fancybox();
```

line 2063-2081 div supposed to show up in fancyfox

```
<div id="car_lightbox" style="background-color:#000; width:100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```

line 2083 simple link for debugging

```
<a class="car_overlay" href="#car_lightbox">open car overlay</a>
```

no errors are shown in console(besides missing images I know of), yet nothing fancybox related seems to be happening

Any help would be really well appreciated.

Comment: You're calling fancybox() on the anchor element.  If you want the div to be fancy boxed, you need to call it on that element and then use the anchor to show it.  Also, you don't need to include the jQuery and jQuery-min files.  One or the other.

Comment: but the instructions on the homepage say to call it on the anchor element http://fancybox.net/howto
and wordpress automatically includes both jQuery-min and jQuery,

Comment: Yes, that's for displaying the embedded HTML content from the anchor.  But you're using the 'inline content' style.  And if you're following the howto, for one, your div needs to be `display: none;`.

Comment: As per the instructions, the display:none should be on the wrapper around the element, which it is.

Comment: I think i'll just go with something other than fancybox, but thank you for trying to help

Comment: It's working fine here.  https://jsfiddle.net/ag9vxoav/

Comment: Weird, almost looks like i'm using pretty much the exact same code as you are, might be something i'm using is conflicting with it

Comment: Post more of your code and i'll take a look.

Comment: the entirety of it is at view-source:http://lykilldivi.kaliber.is/blog/cars/ 
its almost 2200 lines, no need wasting your time trying to comb through that. I don't want to post the source itself since it mostly uses php and I don't want to expose the backend. But thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yea you've got something going one somewhere else that is conflicting or not including correctly.  https://jsfiddle.net/ag9vxoav/  I edited the fiddle to match your code and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to find out what's conflicting. but might just make my own overlay onclick.

Comment: Very weird, if I remove the href="#car_lightbox" and replace it with href="", the fancybox works and opens up with the contents of the anchor, but as soon as I try to insert something into href, it stops working